# PHP Encoding type for string to integer conversion

Tags: php, encoding

I would like to know how to generate a number from a string that contains letters and numbers. The requeriment is that the same string must generate always the same number.

I am trying to find an encoding type in PHP, which returns an integer for a string.

I don't need to convert it back to the string. Is there any such encoding available??

Comment: erm, some example would be good

Comment: If it's a hash, that's certainly not unique.

Comment: @maxhud : exactly what I am doing rite now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the solution.

I was looking for something like crc32.
It gives me an integer for a string.

Thank you guys for your help and I apologize for being unclear again.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). I post here a sample algorithm to generate a small number from a string:

```
// making hex hash from sentence
$s = hash( 'ripemd160', "I'm a dog" );

// taking last 5 hex digits
$s2 = substr( $s, -5 );

// converting hex digits to number
echo hexdec( $s2 );
```

Explanation of the sample algorithm:

- Make a [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) from a string. 'ripemd160' is the name of hash algorighm, other hash algorithms:  "md5", "sha256", "haval160,4", etc.. and "I'm a dog" is a sample of sentence to hash.
- Take only few digits from hash to take a little number. For this I [take last 5 digits](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).
- Finally convert [hex digits to number](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php).

Notice that this is only a sample of multiples ways that you can take to generate a number from an string.

**Testing:**

```
dani@egg-v2:~$ php5
<?php
$a=array( "I'm a dog", "I'm a cat", "I'm a car" );
foreach ($a as $e) {
   $s = hash( 'ripemd160', $e) ;
   $s2 = substr( $s, -5 );
   echo "Hash of $e: " . hexdec( $s2 ) . "\n";
}
?>
Hash of I'm a dog: 147508
Hash of I'm a cat: 23112
Hash of I'm a car: 563887  <-- little change in string but big change in number
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer can  only store a limited amount of data, where as a string might store much more than that. If you convert a string to in integer, somehow, it would always collide with something else (in two words, it's NOT UNIQUE!).... 
Better you choose something else (may be salted MD5?)!